# dynamically change mysqli connection timeout in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, timeout, connection, mysqli

how can I dynamically change MySqli connection timeout using PHP? I found the following manual that you can set an option after a connection is opened, but it says it only support Windows since PHP 5.3.1:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php

I'm using PHP5.2.4, MySQLi (improved version)

the default connection timeout is 20 seconds in my.cnf, but in a special php script I have I'd like to set it to higher like 500 seconds before it times out.

Comment: The manual entry is a bit ambiguous in my mind. It might as well mean, it works everywhere, but on Windows only with PHP 5.3.1 or higher. Are you on a Linux machine? Can you try out?

Answer (score 2):

```
$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 500)
```

[manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php)

However, making a connection from php to mysql is NOT resource intensive.  IMHO, it is a better idea to have a smaller timeout and make multiple connections.  Doing so will free up the connections for other processes.

Comment: His problem (as far as I understand) is that this won't work on his Windows server because he is using PHP < 5.3.0.

Comment: I agree, all my normal connections are subject to 20 second timeout. but this specific script takes long time to run and sometimes idle mysql connection for long, that's why I need longer connection just for this script

Comment: @Yada, Why are you posting the solution the question has already stated not to work? How can we make it work in Windows < PHP 5.3.1?

Answer (score 2):

the correct solution for mysqli is right after an connection is opened, issue the following query to change `session.wait_timeout` to longer:

```sql
SET @@session.wait_timeout=500
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm very sorry for the confusion, but I'm using Linux server, not Windows. I misunderstood the comment in the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php) *"supported on Windows with TCP/IP since PHP 5.3.1"*, I thought that means the option is only supported on Windows server.

OK, so

```
$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 500);
```

will work perfectly for me.

Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and place what you placed here, there :)

Comment: Why did you post TWO answers to this thread?! You should "merge" them and delete one of them.